# ExecuteNonQuery: returning right number

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a procedure that inserts N records and then updates N records. ExecuteNonQuery on that procedure returns 2N. Is there a way to return only number of records updated, i.e. affected in the statement run last?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with SET NOCOUNT OFF/ON inside the stored procedure

You place a SET NOCOUNT ON when the sp starts, thus disabling the count of inserted records, apply the SET NOCOUNT OFF just before the update part of the sp.

[Here a reference to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

At the begining of stored procedure call

`SET NOCOUNT ON`

, and before last statement call

`SET NOCOUNT OFF`